# How to rearranging the components of sequence according to permutation?

Tags: matlab

I have a sequence `r` and i need to rearanging the components of `r` according to the permutation `k` to obtain the sequence :

`y = [y0 y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 y6 y7]` with

`abs(y0) > abs(y1) > abs(y2) > abs(y3) > abs(y4)` and  `abs(y5) > abs(y6) > abs(y7)`

Example :

`r = [-2.3 2.1 2.0 -1.4 1.2 0.5 -0.02]` and `k = [1 2 3 5 4 6 7]`

So

```
y = [-2.3 2.1 2.0 1.2 -1.4 0.5 -0.02]
```

I used this command but I can not find the sequence searched :

```
[~,k] = sort(abs(r),'descend');
 y = r(k);
```

Comment: What is wrong the obtained result? The problem is that there is no unique solution as `abs(y4) > abs(y5)` should not be true. Your code returns `y = -2.3000    2.1000    2.0000   -1.4000    1.2000    0.5000   -0.0200` which satisfies your conditions.

Comment: In my code k is created automatically, while I already have a `k = [1 2 3 5 4 6 7]`.My code gives `k = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]`.

Comment: So, just use `y = r(k);` with the given `k` without recalculated it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is only valid in newer MATLAB versions, but if you have one (not sure when it was introduced, but above 2014b for sure) this will work:

```
y=sort(r,'direction','descend','ComparisonMethod','abs')
```

Comment: I use matlab 2016.Thanks I had the solution.